# Every field has an algebraic closure.

Tags: field-theory

I'm trying to understand the following proof of the book "Field and Galois Theory" by Patrick Morandi:

**Every field $F$ has an algebraic closure.**

Proof: Let $S$ be a set satisfying $\left| S\right|>\max\lbrace\left| F\right|,\left|\mathbb{N}\right|\rbrace $ and consider the following sets:
$$\mathcal{A}=\lbrace K\text{ field }\mid F\subset K\subset S\text{ and }K/F\text{ is algebraic}\rbrace$$
Applying Zorn's lemma one sees that there exists a maximal element $M\in \mathcal{A}$, let us see that this is an algebraic closure of $F$, i.e let us see that $M$ is algebraically closed. First of all notice that for every algebraic extension $L/M$ we have, by a previous lema:
$$\left| L\right|\leq\max\lbrace\left| F\right|,\left|\mathbb{N}\right|\rbrace<\left|S\right| $$
Hence, there exists $f:L\to S$ such that $f\mid_M=Id$. By defining $f(a)+f(b)=f(a+b)$ and $f(a)f(b)=f(ab)$ on $f(L)$ it is easy to check that $f$ is a field homomorphism, $f(L)$ is a field and $f(L)/M$ is a field extension. Since $M$ is maximal in $\mathcal{A}$ then $f(L)=M\Rightarrow L=M$. Hence $M$ is algebraically closed and we are done.

### Questions:

- Why we can find $f:L\to S$ such that such that $f\mid_M=Id$? Of course, by cardinality $\left| L\right|<\left|S\right| \Leftrightarrow$ there exists an injection $f:L\to S$, but that is not the function we are looking for.
- Why $f(L)/M$ is algebraic? Although it is not written in the proof it is obvious that we need the extension to be algebraic, otherwise $f(L)\notin\mathcal{A}$ and we can not use the fact that $M$ is maximal in $\mathcal{A}$.

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Comment: $f$ is bijective if considered from $L\to f(L)$. $f(L)=M=f(M)$ then implies $L=M$.

Comment: @FShrike ups, right that was easy

Comment: Since $L\subset S,$ and $|M|<|S|,$ there are "enough" elements left in $S$ to extend $id:L\to S$ to $f:M\to S.$ Essentially, $|S\setminus L|>|M|\geq |M\setminus L|$

Comment: You might be able to do another Zorn lemma argument to make Thomas’ extension